# Cant Connect SmartCard with winscard.dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I need to read a Smartcard of Document Identity.

I am using winscard.dll in ASP.NET with the execute method:

```
SCardConnect()
```

This function returns the following error:

```
retCode = -2146434970
```

This code number is not supported.

See list of Supported errors at the end.

Method ConnectCard and Values of parameters before sending:

```
hContext = -855572480
readername = "ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0"
Card.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED = 2
Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 = 1
Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1 = 2
hCard = 0
Protocol = 0



public bool connectCard()
    {
        connActive = true;
        retCode = Card.SCardConnect(hContext, readername, Card.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED,
                  Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 | Card.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1, ref hCard, ref Protocol);

        if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(Card.GetScardErrMsg(retCode), "Card not available", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            connActive = false;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Error Codes:**

```
/*===========================================================
'   Error Codes
'===========================================================*/
public const int SCARD_F_INTERNAL_ERROR = -2146435071;
public const int SCARD_E_CANCELLED = -2146435070;
public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_HANDLE = -2146435069;
public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_PARAMETER = -2146435068;
public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_TARGET = -2146435067;
public const int SCARD_E_NO_MEMORY = -2146435066;
public const int SCARD_F_WAITED_TOO_LONG = -2146435065;
public const int SCARD_E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = -2146435064;
public const int SCARD_E_UNKNOWN_READER = -2146435063;
public const int SCARD_E_TIMEOUT = -2146435062;
public const int SCARD_E_SHARING_VIOLATION = -2146435061;
public const int SCARD_E_NO_SMARTCARD = -2146435060;
public const int SCARD_E_UNKNOWN_CARD = -2146435059;
public const int SCARD_E_CANT_DISPOSE = -2146435058;
public const int SCARD_E_PROTO_MISMATCH = -2146435057;
public const int SCARD_E_NOT_READY = -2146435056;
public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_VALUE = -2146435055;
public const int SCARD_E_SYSTEM_CANCELLED = -2146435054;
public const int SCARD_F_COMM_ERROR = -2146435053;
public const int SCARD_F_UNKNOWN_ERROR = -2146435052;
public const int SCARD_E_INVALID_ATR = -2146435051;
public const int SCARD_E_NOT_TRANSACTED = -2146435050;
public const int SCARD_E_READER_UNAVAILABLE = -2146435049;
public const int SCARD_P_SHUTDOWN = -2146435048;
public const int SCARD_E_PCI_TOO_SMALL = -2146435047;
public const int SCARD_E_READER_UNSUPPORTED = -2146435046;
public const int SCARD_E_DUPLICATE_READER = -2146435045;
public const int SCARD_E_CARD_UNSUPPORTED = -2146435044;
public const int SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE = -2146435043;
public const int SCARD_E_SERVICE_STOPPED = -2146435042;
public const int SCARD_W_UNSUPPORTED_CARD = -2146435041;
public const int SCARD_W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD = -2146435040;
public const int SCARD_W_UNPOWERED_CARD = -2146435039;
public const int SCARD_W_RESET_CARD = -2146435038;
public const int SCARD_W_REMOVED_CARD = -2146435037;
```

Comment: Which language tag would you propose?  I had a look at the FAQ (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) and cannot find anything for ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to convert the error code integer (C# by chance?) to an unsigned number. Those are more widely used and far better searchable.

[PCSC-lite](https://pcsclite.apdu.fr/api/group__ErrorCodes.html#ga4a3c56f69570971d366642a563b34a75) documentation states the code `0x80100066` to mean *card unresponsive*. This seems to fit to your problem, therefore idea is, first to try another card, afterwards exchange reader.

Updated: Afterwards I noted, that your error code list seems to be different for some codes, since it list a different number for *unreponsive card*, analyzing the differences may also help.